# AWS API Gateway: 403 forbidden with disabled API key; error from cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

How can happen that with a Lambda/API Gateway combination, if no explicit Cloud Front configuration has been done, in an error response header they mention CloudFront?

```
header: x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
header: x-amz-apigw-id: P3mmbT_DREF8bg=
header: X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
```

Actual problem: with a disabled API key, API keeps responding "forbidden".

UPDATE. As it seems the problem is not related to the Edge API/CloudFront, as the problem with disabled key persists also on changing API type to regional.

UPDATE. I can now disable API key checking as suggested by @Harish i.e. it's not about disabling the API key itself but telling the API whether it's required or not.

What is yet open though is why if created by [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa), there is no option to change this setting in the UI, because there are not single methods.

[image: zappa-methods]

Comment: What response do you expect from the API when you call it with a disabled API key?

Comment: the client sends no key, the API has it disabled. So my expectation is that API accepts the call normally.

Comment: Use [Zappa's `api_key_required` setting](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#api-key) to enable/disable API key requirement for individual routes in your API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you deploy an edge-optimized API, API Gateway sets up an Amazon CloudFront distribution and a DNS record to map the API domain name to the CloudFront distribution domain name. Requests for the API are then routed to API Gateway through the mapped CloudFront distribution.

Source: API Gateway documentation — [Edge-optimized custom domain names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html#edge-optimized-custom-domain-names).

---

To allow calls to a method of a resource in your API without API key, set its `API Key Required` setting to `false`:

[image]

Comment: thank you @Harish KM! I've changed the API type to regional, but still the API remains closed. At least half of my question is now answered. :-)

Comment: @PeterMuryshkin I've updated the answer to show how to make the API accept a call without an API key.

Comment: thank you, Harish! Your hint has helped me in the right direction though I couldn't find the setting edit option in the UI, possibly with ANY selector it's different mode.

Comment: @PeterMuryshkin Click `Method Request` to get to the settings, as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/lOxYoGj.png).

Comment: I see now! thx.

Comment: I am still having this issue after I changed the `API Key Required` property to `false`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JeremyHamm Remember to save the change by clicking the tiny tick mark next to `API Key Required` after you change it from `true` to `false`. Also remember to deploy the API to a stage before testing it: `Actions` menu > `Deploy API`.

Answer (score 5):

Besides setting `API Key Required = false`, I was missing something in `API Gateway` `>` `Custom domain names`:

The API Mapping had no stage selected. When I selected `dev`, the endpoint worked.

[image: Api Gateway Mappings]